# How to compare string with enum in C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
string strName = "John";
public enum Name { John,Peter }

private void DoSomething(string myname)
{
case1:
     if(myname.Equals(Name.John) //returns false
     {

     }

case2:
     if(myname == Name.John) //compilation error
     {

     }

case3:
     if(myname.Equals(Name.John.ToString()) //returns true (correct comparision)
     {

     }
}
```

when I use `.Equals` it is reference compare and when I use `==` it means value compare.

Is there a better code instead of converting the enum value to `ToString()` for comparison? because it destroys the purpose of value type enum and also, `ToString()` on enum is deprecated??

Comment: How come you are comparing strings to enum values? Is there a way to avoid that completely?

Comment: Trying to compare an enumeration to a string is a BAD idea.

Comment: @SecurityHound often this is unavoidable when working on others codebases.

Answer (score 74):

You can use the [`Enum.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499) method to convert a string to the equivalent enumerated value (assuming it exists):

```
Name myName;
if (Enum.TryParse(nameString, out myName))
{
    switch (myName) { case John: ... }
}
```

Comment: This is far better than comparing the `ToString()` value of each of the enumerations. :)

Comment: What's so bad about MyEnumValue.ToString() ?

Comment: @Heinzlmaen - ToString() works, but you'd compare 2 strings a bunch of times (for every enum) - nameString.Equals(JohnEnum.ToString()). And you could have uppercase/lowercase, etc. bugs. Using Enum.TryParse allows you to use a switch statement, which is cleaner in my opinion, and if you have to convert to lowercase etc. you'd only need to do it once in Enum.TryParse(nameString.ToLowerInvariant(), out myName)).

Comment: TryParse also works with 3 parameters, the 2nd one set to `true` will perform a case-insensitive search over the enum set. I've almost never found case sensitive searches handy, using tricks like .ToLower etc in most compares.

Answer (score 43):

You can parse the string value and do enum comparisons.

`Enum.TryParse`: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx

```
Name result;
if (Enum.TryParse(myname, out result))
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case Name.John:
            /* do 'John' logic */
            break;
        default:
            /* unexpected/unspecialized enum value, do general logic */
            break;
    }
}
else 
{
    /* invalid enum value, handle */
}
```

If you are just comparing a single value:

```
Name result;
if (Enum.TryParse(myname, out result) && result == Name.John)
{
     /* do 'John' logic */
}
else 
{
    /* do non-'John' logic */
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you using .NET4 or later you can use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse.aspx). and [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559%28v=vs.80%29) is available for .NET2 and later

```
// .NET2 and later
try
{
    switch (Enum.Parse(typeof(Names), myName))
    {
        case John: ... 
        case Peter: ...
    }
}

// .NET4 and later
Name name;
if (Enum.TryParse(myName, out name))
    switch (name)
    {
        case John: ... 
        case Peter: ...
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be to get the type of the enum, and then the types name.

```
myname.Equals(Enum.GetName(typeof(Name)))
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the given solutions didn't workout for me. I had to do in a slighly different way:

```
Name myName;
if (Enum.TryParse<Name>(nameString, out myName))
{
    switch (myName) { case John: ... }
}
```

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more elegant solution would be an string extension method:

```
public static bool Equals(this string enumString, Name value)
{
    if(Enum.TryParse<Name>(enumString, out var v))
    {
        return value == v;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This way you can directly use .Equals() on the string as in the OPs first example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `Enum.Parse()` method.

```
if(myname.Equals(Enum.Parse(Name.John)) //returns false
 {

 }
```