# How to filter by enum from string in LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, filter, enums, where-clause

Is there a way how to filter data with an enum property using a string?

This is my function in service layer which takes 2 arguments for paging feature and 3rd argument is for filtering projects by their status.

I want to do something like this `projects.Where(x => x.Status == status)` but it throws error because I cannot compare enum with string. Is there some workaround for this?

```
public async Task<ListResult<ProjectDTO>> GetListedProjects(int pageSize, int pageNumber, string status)
{
    var projects = await unitOfWork.ProjectRepository.Get();
    //i cannot filter like this
    projects.Where(x => x.Status == status);
    var orderedProjects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

    var projectList = orderedProjects.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

    var data = projectList.Select(x => ToDTO.ProjectBuild(x)).ToList();
    return new ListResult<ProjectDTO> { Data = data, TotalCount = projectList.TotalItemCount };
}
```

Here is my project model:

```
public class Project : ManagementBaseClass
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public Priority Priority { get; set; }
    //etc just deleted more properties to make this cleaner
}
```

This is my enum which i use for assigning status to projects, tasks etc

```
public enum Status
{
    New = 1,
    Active = 2,
    OnHold = 3,
    Testing = 4,
    Finished = 5,
    Dropped = 6
}
```

Comment: Do You have to use as parametr of the method as `string status`? Why don't You use `Status status` instead?

Comment: @Tatranskymedved yeah this seems incredibly obvious.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to compare string with enum in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508865/how-to-compare-string-with-enum-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I send my status info as a string from my angular client to my server but i am not sure if it gonna deserialize my information into `Status status` parameter in my method. Have to try that.

Comment: Inspect the answers below and choose one that works, you have multiple options. Alternatively, you could send Status as an integer and cast it to `Status`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the string to the enum equivalent

Obviously this code is a rough draft to give you an idea and set you on the right track, you'd have to do null checks on the Parse to prevent exceptions, or use TryParse.

```
public async Task<ListResult<ProjectDTO>> GetListedProjects(int pageSize, int pageNumber, string status)
{
    var projects = await unitOfWork.ProjectRepository.Get();
    //i cannot filter like this
    projects.Where(x => x.Status == (Status)Enum.Parse(typeof(Status), status));
    var orderedProjects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

    var projectList = orderedProjects.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

    var data = projectList.Select(x => ToDTO.ProjectBuild(x)).ToList();
    return new ListResult<ProjectDTO> { Data = data, TotalCount = projectList.TotalItemCount };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the string value:

```
private static TEnum? GetEnum<TEnum>(string value) where TEnum : struct
{
    TEnum result;

    return Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(value, out result) ? (TEnum?)result : null;
}

public async Task<ListResult<ProjectDTO>> GetListedProjects(int pageSize, int pageNumber, string status)
{
    var projects = await unitOfWork.ProjectRepository.Get();
    //i cannot filter like this
    projects.Where(x => x.Status == GetEnum<Status>(status));
    var orderedProjects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

    var projectList = orderedProjects.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

    var data = projectList.Select(x => ToDTO.ProjectBuild(x)).ToList();
    return new ListResult<ProjectDTO> { Data = data, TotalCount = projectList.TotalItemCount };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing `string` as such:

```
public async Task<ListResult<ProjectDTO>> GetListedProjects(int pageSize, int pageNumber, string status)
{
    var projects = await unitOfWork.ProjectRepository.Get();
    //i cannot filter like this
    projects.Where(x => x.Status == status);
    var orderedProjects = projects.OrderBy(x => x.Name);

    var projectList = orderedProjects.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

    var data = projectList.Select(x => ToDTO.ProjectBuild(x)).ToList();
    return new ListResult<ProjectDTO> { Data = data, TotalCount = projectList.TotalItemCount };
}
```

When you should be passing the enum

```
public async Task<ListResult<ProjectDTO>> GetListedProjects(int pageSize, int pageNumber, Status status)
```

You could also pass in string, and create a `Status` variable and with some switch statement, you could set it to the correct enum. I don't like converting a `string` to an `enum` as some of the answers show. Error prone in my opinion, you're better off trying to either A) resolve the string to a `Status` or B) just pass in the `Status` enum to avoid any conflict.

Comment: Or, for the last paragraph, you could just `TryParse`. Imagine a `switch` statement for a 50 or 100 size enum that's used for billing codes in a corporate product, it's prone to its own bugs by hardcoding strings and introducing possible spelling mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Before you call `projects.Where(x => x.Status == status);` you should try and parse that string value of `status` into the Status Enum.

You can use either `Enum.Parse` which throws an exception if the parse fails or you can use `Enum.TryParse` that returns a bool based on the success/failure of the parsing operation.

Comment: Yeah it was just a rough draft, just wanted to show what I want to archieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert the Status enum to String and filter it. You can even search by part of the Status name if you use the Contains method:

```
projects.Where(x => x.Status.ToString() == status);     //To filter by exact input value

projects.Where(x => x.Status.ToString().Contains(status));     //To filter by part of the name search, for example if the input status is any of "N" or "Ne" or "New", the query returns the row with Status = 1
```