# C# Adding CSV to a list

Tags: c#, list, csv

I try to add the containing of a csv file to a new list. It's a list of different types of people with caracteristics like the function, a matricule, the last name, the firstname and a sex. So I managed to read the file but I don't really know how to process to add the containing of the file to my list.Here is my code :

```
  `private static void ReadTest() 
    {
        int count = 0;
        string line;
        Char c = ';';

        StreamReader file= new StreamReader("Listing.csv");

        while ((line= file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] substrings = line.Split(c);

            foreach (var substring in substrings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(substring);
            }

            count++;
        }

        fichier.Close();
        System.Console.WriteLine("Number of lines : {0}.", count);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Personnel> Workers = new List<Personnel>();

    }
```

'

Comment: If "line" in your loop is a person, with comma separated attributes, you're 99% of the way there.  Either parse the attributes into a new Personnel object, and then add that object to a List<Personnel>, or add "line" to a List<string> and return that from the reader.  Then you can parse the "line" collection to Personnel in a different method.  All you're missing from your code is the List<string> to store the values you are reading from the file.

Comment: Yeah, seems like all you need to do now after the split is basically `Personnel p = new Personnel()` and then fill the properties in like, `p.LName = substrings[0]`, `p.FName = substrings[1]` etc... and finally add p to your list. You just need to map the columns to the correct properties.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `CSVHelper`, it will be as simple as the following:

```
var csv = new CsvReader( textReader );
var records = csv.GetRecords<Personnel>();
//then loop through
foreach( var record in records )
{

}
```

you just need to install the nuget package:

```
Install-Package CsvHelper
```

Check [this](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) for more information.

Comment: This is a school project and I have constraints including not to use CsvHelper

Answer (score 1):

Replace the foreach loop with something like the following:

```
var person = new Personnel(); 
person.firstname = substrings[0];
person.lastname = substrings[1]; 
person.function = substrings[2]; 
//continue until all variables assigned. 
Workers.Add(person);
```

Also, if the Workers list is not a static list, then make ReadTest return a List and create a list within the function.

Like this:

```
private static List<Personnel> ReadTest() 
{
    int count = 0;
    string line;
    Char c = ';';

    StreamReader file= new StreamReader("Listing.csv");
    var Workers = new List<Personnel>();

    while ((line= file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        String[] substrings = line.Split(c);

        var person = new Personnel(); 
        person.firstname = substrings[0];
        person.lastname = substrings[1]; 
        person.function = substrings[2]; 
        //continue until all variables assigned. 
        Workers.Add(person); 

        count++;
    }

    file.Close();
    System.Console.WriteLine("Number of lines : {0}.", count);
    return Workers; 
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<Personnel> Workers = ReadTest();

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have another question. One of the caracteristics to add is an enum type, so how can I make it correspond to the substrings?

Comment: Here is an SO on how to find an enum from a string:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508865/how-to-compare-string-with-enum-in-c-sharp/11508909