# Enum to string value or make use of enum in if condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, enums

I have  a enum that has multiple values (I have kept only one below inside the enum). I am being passed this string "Online System" from the UI. Is there a way I can make use of this enum to do the condition rather than hardcoding like below.

```
if( types.type == "Online System" )

  public enum Type
        {
            [EnumMember]
            Windows
            ,[EnumMember]
            OnlineSystem
        }
```

**Update**

Also, when I number the enum values to Windows = 1, OnlineSystem = 2, will there be any problem? This code is already there, but I am gona number like this, will this create any side effect for codes that might use this already without numbering?

Comment: Whats the datatype of `types.type`? Its the enum or string?

Comment: @er-mfahhgk: Apparently its a string thats why I have put string value there in quotes

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11508909/795683

Comment: @Learner, I added my answer below, You need to pass string value like `OnlineSystem`.

Comment: @Learner , check this => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367723/get-enum-from-description-attribute

Comment: @er-mfahhgk: Thank you so much for your kind help, that link was quite useful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can decorate your Enum with Description Attribute

```
  public enum Type
  {
    [Description("Windows")]
    Windows,
    [Description("Online System")]
    OnlineSystem
  }
```

Then You could write a method to use reflection to fetch the description of given Enum Value (Value to compare to).

```
public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());

    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(DescriptionAttribute),
        false);

    if (attributes != null &&
        attributes.Length > 0)
        return attributes[0].Description;
    else
        return value.ToString();
}
```

This would enable you to check

```
var type = "Online System";
if(  type == GetEnumDescription(Type.OnlineSystem))
{
}
```

Comment: Anu, thank you so much, just a quick question, the parameter to GetEnumDescription shouldn't start with "this" keyword?

Comment: @Learner 'this' keyword is associated with Extension method. The method in the example not an extension method, which is why it is missing. You can read more on extension methods here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods