# Access and check entries from an enum in C#

Tags: c#, enums

Say, I have an enum which goes like this

```
public enum Items
{
   Fruits,
   Nuts,
   Chocolate
}
```

And I have a method in another class that has the enum its argument, like

```
public void Method(Items item)
```

In the method, I want to evaluate the enum that is passed, something akin to :

```
if(item == "Fruit")
{
  print("Something");
}
```

But since the enum entries are not strings, I cannot do that. Is there a way to do the above operation elegantly?

Comment: You can use item.ToString()..

Comment: What's wrong with `if (item == Items.Fruits)`

Comment: @MichaelGabbay Of course. Why didn't I think of that? Thank you so much

Comment: @Zer0 That works too. Thank you for clearing that up?

Comment: Happy i helped :)

Comment: No problem.  If this question is solved please mark something as an answer.  You can upvote multiple answers that helped too.

Comment: By the way, if you want to allow access to the enum via a string (say, you have a config entry that specifies "Fruit" as the default Items type), you can use `Enum.Parse` or better still `Enum.TryParse`

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to compare with a string

```
if(item.ToString().Equals("Fruit"))
{
  print("Something");
}
```

Or even better use switch case to compare with the enum itself.

```
switch(item) {
    case Items.Fruits:
          Console.Writeline("something");
           break;
    case Items.Nuts:
          Console.Writeline("something else");
           break;
    default:
          Console.writeline("something else 2");
           break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

`if (item == Items.Fruits)`

I'm really not a fan of the `ToString()` answers as you're creating a string for no reason.

By default, an `Enum` is backed by `Int32`.  So you could also compare using casts like `(int)Items.Fruits` if you wanted.

Do keep in mind this won't work if you're using the `[Flags]` attribute on your `Enum`.

Answer (score -1):

The most simple solution is to use item.ToString().

Another solution you can find here:
[how to compare string with enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508865/how-to-compare-string-with-enum-in-c-sharp)

Hope i helped